# How Windows Phone's People hub retrive Facebook Friends' contact Info?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I just brought a new windows phone and started using People hub app. Its amazing way to stay connected with your friends without installing any other 3rd Party app for facebook. This app also synced my facebook friends' contact list in my mobile. "People Hub" retrieve the friends' email, contact number and other information, but I don't think that any other 3rd party app can retrieve this info. I read a related [blog](http://andrewtechhelp.com/andrews-tech-opinions/129-facebook-integration-on-windows-phone-the-problem-being-a-3rd-party-app) but It still can't answer my question.

Comment: You haven't stated what your question actually is!

Answer (score 0):

The phone doesn't check facebook.  The phone syncs with your live account.  Your live account gets the data from facebook, as well as LinkedIn and Twitter, and sends all the data to the phone at once.  Saves energy in communications by putting it all together instead of making separate calls to the different services.

Comment: Yes but i didn't get how my live account can access my friends private data, like emails, phone numbers and pictures? I thought facebook doesn't allow any app to retrieve all this infos.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with how Live interacts with Facebook, but I do know that if your friend has a phone number on fb, that is visible to you, then your live account will sync it with your phone.  Basically, all of the info that is in your phone came through facebook.  There may be private APIs that facebook allows MS to use with the phone.